# PHP - Continue Execute Another Looping After Execute Looping

Tags: php, timeout, connection-timeout

I have thousand email address in my database. I want to send a message to them. But every time I send it show error "500 Internal Server Error. Request Timeout. This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout".

I have set maximum_execution_time, set_time_limit, or other something like this to 0 (or unlimited). It will Request Timeout in the end. Is there any solution?

My code

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user");
while($q=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  // Send email to $q['user_email']
  echo "sent to ".$q['user_email'];
}
?>
```

Can I execute another loop after successfully executing a loop without timeout?

Maybe something like this?

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user LIMIT 0,99");
while($q=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  // Send email to $q['user_email']
  echo "sent to ".$q['user_email'];
}
//do another looping
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user LIMIT 100,199");
while($q=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  // Send email to $q['user_email']
  echo "sent to ".$q['user_email'];
}
?>
```

Comment: yes... if your first loop works then your second should as well

Comment: `set-time-limit` and others doesn't work in `safe-mode`. See [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an issue within set_time_out when looping.

A possible solution is to set_time_out(0) before every iteration.